# Using LINQ to Group, concatenate and Counting

Tags: c#, linq

Using Linq i need to summarize table (1) into table (2)

### Table (1)

| Race | Swimmer | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| freestyle | A | USA |
| freestyle | B | USA |
| freestyle | C | UK |
| freestyle | D | ITA |
| butterfly | E | USA |
| butterfly | F | UK |
| butterfly | G | UK |
| butterfly | H | ITA |

### Table (2)

| Race | Count | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| freestyle | 4 | USA(2)-UK(1)-ITA(1) |
| butterfly | 4 | USA(1)-UK(2)-ITA(1) |

Where Race is the Race Type, Count=the number of Swimmers in the Race, Country= summary of
the number of swimmers per each country in the indicated form.
I managed to use grouping and join text using string.Join() method but i could not add the count
beside each country as shown above

```
var _s= _races.GroupBy(x => new { x.Race })
                      .Select(y => new
                       {
                         Race= y.Key.Race,
                         Count= y.Count(x => x.Race!= null),
                         Country= string.Join(" - ", y.Select(z =>z.Country).Distinct()) 
                                                 
                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace the line

```
Country= string.Join(" - ", y.Select(z =>z.Country).Distinct())
```

With:

```
Country= string.Join(" - ", y.Select(z =>$"{z.Country}({y.Where(c=>c.Country==z.Country).Count()})").Distinct())
```

It's not the best solution, but it keeps your way of doing query.

If you want this query to be little bit more optimized, then you may introduce `distinctCountries` variable f.e.:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.race)
       .Select(y => {
           var distinctCountries = y.Select(z => z.country).Distinct();
           return new
           {
               Race = y.Key,
               Count = y.Count(),
               Country = string.Join(" - ", distinctCountries.Select(z => $"{z}({y.Where(c => c.country == z).Count()})").Distinct())

           };

       });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is close, but the problem is the counting (for ex USA(2), UK(1)) is not correct when i apply your solution

Comment: Are you sure have the same dataset as above? I double checked that, and i have exactly what you asked for.

Comment: You are right it is working perfectly now. I have different dataset and the problem was in filters were not applied in the right location. Again Thank you